# Cordova/PhoneGap How do I post a game score page to Facebook?

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova

I have a game that was done using HTML and JS, and is being compiled as an iPhone project using cordova/phonegap.

Everything works fine, and I have also managed to integrate the official cordova facebook plugin which can be found here:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

so users can now invoke the Post to Wall dialog box for Facebook.

However, I would actually like users to post an in-screen image for my game (i.e the content inside a div container)

I really have no idea how to do that at all, so it would be great if someone can point me in the right direction.

I have thought of using JS or HTML canvas to capture the div, but I am not sure how well that will work on the iPhone. Pardon me, this is my first time trying to develop an application using cordova.

Thanx alot!